# Is it possible to replace textarea with div for reading input in FastAPI (or Flask)?

Tags: html, flask, input, textarea, fastapi

I've just discovered that using `<div contentEditable="true">` provides an automatically expanding text area for input, which seems better suited to my purpose than a `textarea`. Unfortunately, I'm unable to read div text with FastAPI.

Here is my testing code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

import uvicorn
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Form
from starlette.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/form', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def form_get():
    return """<form method="post"> 
    <textarea  id="input" name="ta" rows="2">very
    long
    textarea
    text</textarea>
    <div name="da" contentEditable="true">
       even <br/> longer <br/> div <br/> area <br/> text <br/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit"/> 
    </form>"""


@dataclass
class SimpleModel:
    ta: str = Form(None)
    da: str = Form(None)


@app.post('/form')
def form_post(form_data: SimpleModel = Depends()):
    print(f'form_data: {form_data}')
    return form_data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

Any idea how to read `div` text? Optionally solution with Flask could be fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you’re facing is due to the fact that the  element in HTML does not have a name attribute and is not considered a form control, so its content won’t be included in the form data when the form is submitted.

If you want to submit content from a  element, you could use JavaScript to copy the content of the  into a hidden  field when the form is submitted. Here’s an example of how you could do this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

import uvicorn
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Form
from starlette.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/form", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def form_get():
    return """
        <form method="post" onsubmit="copyContent()"> 
            <textarea id="input" name="ta" rows="2">very
            long
            textarea
            text</textarea>
            <div id="da" contentEditable="true">
            even <br/> longer <br/> div <br/> area <br/> text <br/>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput" name="da">
            <input type="submit"/> 
        </form>

        <script>
        function copyContent() {
            var divContent = document.getElementById("da").innerText;
            document.getElementById("hiddenInput").value = divContent;
        }
        </script>
"""


@dataclass
class SimpleModel:
    ta: str = Form(None)
    da: str = Form(None)


@app.post("/form")
def form_post(form_data: SimpleModel = Depends()):
    ta = form_data.ta
    da = form_data.da
    print(":::::::::> ta")
    print(ta)
    print(":::::::::> da")
    print(da)
    return form_data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", reload=True)
```

a JavaScript function copyContent() is called when the form is submitted. This function copies the text content from the  with id="da" into a hidden  field with id="hiddenInput". The hidden input field also has name="da", so its value will be included in the form data when the form is submitted.